# Windows 11 enabled device encryption on OS using TPM 2.0 but doesn't detect TPM during boot

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker, windows-11

I have installation of Windows 11 home edition.

Today, out of nowhere, I found that all disks are encrypted using BitLocker and unable to boot since it's asking for recovery key.

Eventually I was able to retrieve recovery keys from MS account online and boot. But the problem persists. Every time I boot, it asks me for the long recovery key which is not ideal. I tried adding PIN or simple password using manage-bde.exe but it refuses because Windows license is home edition.

I also noticed TPM 2.0 is enabled in the BIOS (I have not changed any settings). But for some reason, TPM is not working. What should I do?

Comment: Can you start in BIOS and ensure TPM is enabled?

Comment: @John I already did that. TPM is enabled

Comment: Please provide tdhe Output of the command that lists which protectors BitLocker is using. BitLocker cannot be enabled on Windows Home on your system disk. So are you using Device Encryption by chance?

Comment: If you no longer want Device Encryption, make a disk image for safety, then unencrypt the disk.

Comment: @Ramhound Found the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Apparently, Windows 11 require Secure Boot to use the TPM 2.0 feature. Since it was disabled, Windows couldn't TPM.

I just enabled Secure Boot in BIOS and it worked.

Comment: I still maintain you DO NOT have Windows 11 Home or you are not actually using BitLocker but you are instead using Device Encryption. Yes; Windows 11 requires Secure Boot and TPM 2.0 to be enabled (or use the appropriate byapass registry key).

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, seems like the case. I was helping my friend over phone call. Maybe it was device encryption. I didn't even knew these are 2 different things.

Comment: "Device encryption" is, technically, still BitLocker under the hood – just a very restricted "Home edition" version of BitLocker that _requires_ TPM usage as well as Secure Boot usage.

Comment: @user1686 So secure boot is optional for bitlocker but compulsory for device encryption?

Comment: I'm trying to find better sources regarding that. It seems that [_automatic_](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-bitlocker) (out of the box) encryption requires Secure Boot, whether it's the Pro version (BitLocker) or Home (Device Encryption). Meanwhile I'm pretty sure that _manually_ enabling BitLocker in Pro does not require Secure Boot (at least it didn't in Win10; can't speak for Win11), though enabling SB is still a good idea as it makes TPM-based auto-unlock less fragile. I'm not sure about manually enabling Device Encryption in Home, though.